# Ext js Pivot Grid Store wrong type

Tags: extjs

I have a Ext JS (Version 7.3.1) pivot grid like this fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3col

When i click on Test it will output the grid store type. In this case it outputs "memory" but it's an ajax store, so (i guess) cause of this i can't reload with a simple store.load().

What do i need to do to request pivot grid store ajax again?

I already tried switching store. I switched matrix to remote, I tried with direct proxy too. But everytime it will output memory store. So i can't reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used a pivotgrid, but as far as I can see the pivotgrid itself creates an arraystore during initialization, which contains then probably the calculated data. If you want to access your store in the fiddle - which is defined in the *matrix* config - you could simply access the matrix and execute here for example the reload function of your store.

Analogous to your code in the fiddle it would look like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('pivot_grid').getMatrix().store.reload()

// console.log(Ext.getCmp('pivot_grid').getMatrix().store.getProxy().type)
// --> ajax
```